# Finding FONC and Maximising a utility function

Tags: derivatives, optimization, maxima-minima, economics, utility

So we were discussing a utility function in class today and I'm not sure how my teacher arrived at the First Order Necessary Condition that he did (using substitution)

We want to maximise the function $$U(a, b)$$ where $$a = y - pb$$

a is good 1 and b is good 2, whereas y is your income and p is price of good 2 (he got rid of p1 by stating that the price of good 1 = 1, so we just have p (no subscript as "it would be trivial now")

The FONC (with respect to b) that he arrived at is $$U_{1}(a, b)  \frac{∂a,b}{∂b} + U_{2}(a, b) = 0$$

I'm completely at a loss to how he arrived there. I think my differentiation is rusty and I'm differentiating U(a, b) with respect to b, wrong.

Apologies if this is a bit vague, he rushed through this in the last 3 minutes of class and I might not have caught it all.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: It is just the chain rule : $$\frac{\partial }{\partial b} U(a(b),b) = \frac{\partial U}{\partial a} \frac {\partial a}{\partial b} + \frac {\partial U}{\partial b}$$ and it should be zero if $b \in (0, \frac y p)$ is an interior solution.

Comment: The term $\frac{\partial a,b}{\partial b}$ doesn´t make sense to me.